# VsCode - Add Preloaded module from extraPath

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have added a module within the extraPath options (/Applications/Autodesk/maya2018/devkit/other/pymel/extras/completion/py). It takes too long, because is a very long module, so I would like to know if there is any way to add that module into the preLoaded modules options, to improve the autocomplete time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify modules to pre-load for IntelliSense using [`python.autoComplete.preloadModules`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_autocomplete-settings). If you're saying you are specifying the module and it isn't being picked up because its location through [`python.autoComplete.extraPaths`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_autocomplete-settings), then please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.